# Jmeter - Standard Ramp Up Time

Tags: load, jmeter

How do we decide Ramp Up time w.r.t. Threads
When I run 24000 Threads with 1200 secs it works fine but when I reduce to 1000 secs I got random error (503) but when I reduce to 500 - 800 I gets 50% error and so on. Is there any standard for Threads vs Ramp-up ratio?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ramp up time is your load profile decision.
It is up to you and business to decide how users arrive on your application.
You need to be realistic.

The more you reduce it the more you can get errors because it means you have a lot of users coming in a very short time ( newsletter like or morning connection...)

The errors you get are what is expected from a load test, ie to reveal the weak points of configuration , infrastructure or application development.